# How to add a property to the Properties window in the Entity Framework Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-designer

Is there a way to add a custom property to the Properties window for an entity Entity Framework designer? I've extended the T4 files to auto generate some repositories but I only want to do that if an entity is an Aggregate Root.  I'd love to add a True/False "Is Aggregate Root" property for entities....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible [through extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.entity.design.extensibility.aspx). The book [Entity framework 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/mostarda/) contains whole part about different extensions for EF designer and code generation. There is also [project](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DesignerExtStartKit) which should simplify process of extension creations.

Comment: Any idea how to get started with Visual Studio 2012? The project you're linking to exists only for VS2010. I managed to install it into VS2012, but the properties do not appear in the Entity Designer.